# Using grid to modify vcd::mosaic plots

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data, r-grid, mosaic-plot

I want to use `grid` to modify mosaic plots that I create with the `vcd` package.  Specifically, I want to add precisely positioned line segments.  Here is a minimal example:

```
library(vcd)
myDF <- expand.grid(fac1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), fac2 = c('y', 'z'))
mosaic(fac2 ~ fac1, data = myDF, pop = FALSE)
```

The result is this plot:

[image: minimal mosaic plot]

I would like to use `grid.segments()` to draw a horizontal segment under the "fac2" label and as wide as the plotted cells.  This would be simple if I could use `seekViewport()` to navigate to the viewport that holds the "fac2" label.  But I can't.  Here is the problem:

```
> getNames()
> [1] "rect:fac1=a,fac2=y" "rect:fac1=a,fac2=z" "rect:fac1=b,fac2=y" "rect:fac1=b,fac2=z" 
  [5] "rect:fac1=c,fac2=y" "rect:fac1=c,fac2=z" "GRID.text.1"        "GRID.text.2"        
  [9] "GRID.text.3"        "GRID.text.4"        "GRID.text.5"        "GRID.text.6"        
 [13] "GRID.text.7"
```

When I run `seekViewport("cell:GRID.text.2")` or anything like it, I get an error message:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_downviewport, name$name, strict) : 
  Viewport 'cell:GRID.text.2' was not found
```

(The "cell:" prefix is part of the `vcd` viewport-naming scheme.  And by contrast, commands like `seekViewport("cell:fac1=a,fac2=y")` work perfectly.)

Is there a way to navigate to the viewport that holds the "fac2" label?  And if not, what is the best way to precisely position a line segment below that label?

Comment: I think you are looking at the `grob` names rather than the viewports. You can see these by either `grid.ls(viewports=T)` or `current.vpTree(all=T)`, after the plot call. I dont know how to navigate to the viewport with the label, but this seems to get you close to what you want: `vp <- vpPath(current.vpTree()[[2]][[1]][[1]]$name , "base", "margin_top")` ;
`grid.segments(y0=0.35,y1=0.35, gp=gpar(col="red", lwd=3), vp=vp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment above, [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) provides the necessary information.  Among other things, the code in my original post was problematic because `getNames()` returns grob names, not viewport names.

The simplest way to draw the line segment is to draw the figure as above, and then

```
nn <- seekViewport("margin_top")  ## Drill down to the viewport[margin_top]
grid.segments(0, .5, 1, .5)
upViewport(nn)                    ## Return to top level viewport, here viewport[ROOT]
```

The result is this plot:

[image: mosaic plot with line segment between x–axis labels]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer this. Nice to see that there's such an elegant solution! Hope you don't mind the couple of edits I just made.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien -- those edits are definitely helpful, especially for people like me who sometimes have trouble navigating viewports.  Thank you.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I just edited again, to use `upViewport()` instead of `popViewport()` (which removes the viewport from the tree as it leaves it)!